# Call a Var returning function from one worksheet from another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a variable returning function in one worksheet That I wish to call from another worksheet. How do I do this?

```
Function DoUntilOption() As String()
 Dim array1(10) As String
 Dim matrix2(10, 10) As String
...Processing matrix2...
 DoUntilOption = matrix2()
End Function
```

Comment: another worksheet? Or workbook? When you add your function in a module you should be able to call it from any worksheet in that workbook

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out;

```
   matrix = Sheets("NameofSheet").DoUntilOption
```